# Getting data in a HABTM relationship, formatting and sending with Cake's mail-component

Tags: email, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, opml

Maybe it is a simple question, but I don't know how to approach it.
I have a HABTM-relationship between `Podcasts` and `Users` and its basic baked application in `CakePHP 2.3.6`.
A User can "subscribe" to podcasts.

I'd like to

1. **get all podcasts** of the currently logged-in user
2. send a file (.opml, a XML-format) to the currently logged-in User's **email** using CakePHP-emailcomponent containing fields of the podcasts table in a specific formatting.

---

**1. getting all podcasts:** this is what I have.
`debug($this->viewVars)` shows me that the array is `false`.. Why?

*Model/Podcast.php*

```
public function getPodcastsByUserId($userId = null) {
    if(empty($userId)) return false;
    $podcasts = $this->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
             array('table' => 'podcasts_users',
                'alias' => 'PodcastsUser',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'PodcastsUser.user_id' => $userId,
                    'PodcastsUser.podcast_id = Podcast.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'group' => 'Podcast.id'
    ));
    return $podcasts;
}
```

*UsersController.php*

```
public function showMyPodcasts() {
   $userId = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.Id');
   $this->loadModel('Podcast');
   $podcasts = $this->Podcast->getPodcastsByUserId($userId);
   $this->set('podcasts', $podcasts);
}
```

---

**2. sending a file**

Just a basic idea or approach would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

CakeEmail is very well documented here with examples, explanation...etc here:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html